# Firebase download priority in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, download

this is my first question here so I'm sorry if I make some mistakes.

I have an app using Firebase where different data should be downloaded in a specific order.

The first block download new employees, the second new elevators and the third new maintenances.

At the moment new data are downloaded randomly, so it could happen that a maintenance related to an elevator is downloaded before the elevator itself generating an error.

I need elevators to be downloaded before maintenances. How could I do that?

```
AppDelegate.firDatabase?.child(Stringhe.keyEmployeesDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.createNewEmployee(snapshot: snapshot)
})

AppDelegate.firDatabase?.child(Stringhe.keyElevatorsDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.createNewElevator(snapshot: snapshot)
})

AppDelegate.firDatabase?.child(Stringhe.keyMaintenancesDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.collectMaintenanceData(snapshot: snapshot)
    if self.checkIfMaintenanceIsComplete() { self.insertMaintenance() }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be just to nest your calls.

```
AppDelegate.firDatabase?.child(Stringhe.keyEmployeesDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
  self.createNewEmployee(snapshot: snapshot)

  //After new employees, get elevators
  AppDelegate.firDatabase?.child(Stringhe.keyElevatorsDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.createNewElevator(snapshot: snapshot)

    //After elevators, get maintenance
    AppDelegate.firDatabase?.child(Stringhe.keyMaintenancesDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
      self.collectMaintenanceData(snapshot: snapshot)
      if self.checkIfMaintenanceIsComplete() { self.insertMaintenance() }
    })
  })
})
```

As a small aside, you can add a single constant for your databaseRef so you don't have to keep typing out the same thing over and over:

```
guard let db = AppDelegate.firDatabase else { return }
db.child(Stringhe.keyEmployeesDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
  self.createNewEmployee(snapshot: snapshot)

  db.child(Stringhe.keyElevatorsDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.createNewElevator(snapshot: snapshot)

    db.child(Stringhe.keyMaintenancesDatabase).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
      self.collectMaintenanceData(snapshot: snapshot)
      if self.checkIfMaintenanceIsComplete() { self.insertMaintenance() }
    })
  })
})
```

**Edit:** I was just taking another look here and I wanted to point out that observing `.childAdded` doesn't make a lot of logical sense to me, unless you always add a new employee, elevator, and maintenance every time any of those are needed.  Maybe I am making too many assumptions about your business logic, but the way this is structured it'd only work when a new employee is added - otherwise the elevators and maintenance fetches would never trigger.